# I am yet to grow old

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is delay
>   My infix means old
>   My suffix can’t be seen
>   I am yet to grow old

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be

> adolescent - a youngish person not an adult

My prefix is delay

> ado - commotion or fuss will cause delay

My infix means old

> ole - a dialect spelling of old

My suffix can’t be seen

> scent - in the air it is smelled but not seen